Air vent pipe in Hyundai cooling system
I was browsing a Hyundai Azera service manual when I came across this part in the cooling system section.
I understand a thing or two about the cooling system, but I have never heard of this.
What does it do?
Any information is really appreciated.
The engine code is G6DB


What year(s) of Azera is this for?

Probably 2008, give or take.

I did a look-up on the G6DB engine and it was used up until 2008, but not beyond. It's the 3.3L. I had a 2008 Azera with the 3.8L (G6DA) engine in it. As far as the part goes, I think the air vent pipe allows for the engine to burp all of the air out of the engine, that way you don't get any hot spots within the engine during operations. Just my thinking, but not sure.

Thanks a lot. Your answer agrees with another mechanic's who offered to help. The answer is logical. I wonder why there is not much literature about it.

The only thing I found about this topic is a little ventilation valve, usually installed on the radiator.

I sold my 2007 Azera (same engine) many years ago, so being prepared to answer this question must be the reason why I never got rid of the shop manual.
Actually, I can't answer the question, but I can provide another diagram that shows how the "air vent pipe", also called "breather hose" is connected to other components and how it handles air flow. (There are numerous other diagrams that show the same part being called by these two different names.)
There is no commentary on function of the pipe / hose in this manual. It appears to have bidirectional airflow depending on engine load.
Perhaps someone more expert can comment on what the diagram means. Paulster, are you listening?


The diagram shown describes the emissions system  the positive crankcase ventilation system. It's not about the pipe in my question, which belongs to the cooling system.
